# Rails return number of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm learning rails and I'm just trying to get the basics down.

I just installed devise and created a home controller.  If I want to get the number of users (just return the number of records in the db), what should I do from the home controller?  It should interact with a model, right?  Can the `home` controller interact with the `users` model and the `home` model? Or is that bad practice?

I know I could do a simple google search for this, but I have a lot of questions and Stackoverflow is legit. :)

Take it a step further?

How would I get a 'live feed' so that the count changes on the home page when a record is added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a count of the users using `User.count`.

In your template, you can add something like

```
There are <%= User.count %> users.
```

Comment: Is it bad form to put that query directly in the view?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you really don't want a query in your view, you could assign it in the controller like `@user_count = User.count`, then use `@user_count` in the view.

Comment: Yes, it breaks the MVC pattern. You should not trigger SQL queries from your views.

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers can interact with any number of models and if they couldn't, you wouldn't be getting much done ;)

As for the "live feed", that's tricky.  You probably want to use something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Comment: That sounds pretty good. My main question is still 'how do I get the number of users and display it on the home page?'...

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
User.all.length
User.count
```

should work, where the first one is highly inefficient and the second one much better Rails style.

It's not necessarily a bad idea to directly access that. Why not?

Comment: I know, `count` is way more efficient. Should have probably mentioned that.